# React-Table keep state of selected rows

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

Am trying to keep the state of selected checkboxes for a react-table v7. I have a checkbox that can select multiple rows at once and works great, the issue is the table can't maintain that state once a dialog opens up for batch actions. The checkboxes become unchecked immediately the dialog is opened even though the selected rows data is still available. I just need the checkboxes to keep state. The data is fetched from a graphql api and the polling is set to 0

Most of the code used is the same as the documentation

```
const TableContainer = ({ columns, data }) => {
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      page,
      prepareRow,
      canPreviousPage,
      canNextPage,
      pageOptions,
      pageCount,
      gotoPage,
      nextPage,
      previousPage,
      setPageSize,
      setGlobalFilter,
      selectedFlatRows,
      state: { pageIndex, pageSize, globalFilter },
    } = useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
        defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
        initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10 },
      },
      useFilters,
      // useExpanded,
      useGlobalFilter,
      useSortBy,
      usePagination,
      useRowSelect,
      (hooks) => {
        hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
          {
            id: "selection",
            Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
              <Checkbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            ),
            Cell: ({ row }) => {
              return <Checkbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />;
            },
          },
          ...columns,
        ]);
      }
    ); // return
```

Any inputs in the react hooks are able to keep the data entered well without issue. Only change is on the table. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by setting auto resets for cells, rows, and columns on false. [Here](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/row-selection?from=reactTableV7&original=https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect) you can read about this fix.

```
const TableContainer = ({ columns, data }) => {
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      page,
      prepareRow,
      canPreviousPage,
      canNextPage,
      pageOptions,
      pageCount,
      gotoPage,
      nextPage,
      previousPage,
      setPageSize,
      setGlobalFilter,
      selectedFlatRows,
      state: { pageIndex, pageSize, globalFilter },
    } = useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
        defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
        initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10 },
        //Add this
        autoResetSelectedRows: false,
        autoResetSelectedCell: false,
        autoResetSelectedColumn: false,
      },
      useFilters,
      // useExpanded,
      useGlobalFilter,
      useSortBy,
      usePagination,
      useRowSelect,
      (hooks) => {
        hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
          {
            id: "selection",
            Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
              <Checkbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            ),
            Cell: ({ row }) => {
              return <Checkbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />;
            },
          },
          ...columns,
        ]);
      }
    ); // return
```